# Short story - Cars on permanent journeys until ozone hole burns them all

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

My recollection is of a highway circling the world, people living in their cars until finally a hole in the ozone breaks through then expands, burning them all.

It was in English, I believe it was in an anthology; I read it maybe 30 years ago.

Maybe Bradbury?

I think that it was a third person narrator.  It told the story of how the road got wider, more people started driving in cars, how the air was full of fumes and hydrocarbons, then the sun broke through the ozone layer, melting the pavement, burning the cars.

Read it about the same time as *Doctor Rat* by William Kotzwinkle

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Whose perspective was this told from? How did they bulk it out into a story?

Comment: There's a [Doctor Who episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gridlock_(Doctor_Who)) with a similar idea.  WoG on that is that it is a nod to _Judge Dredd_.  Looking into it, led to TV Tropes' [Futuristic Superhighway](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FuturisticSuperhighway), but nothing jumped out on that list.

Comment: No, I don't think its in there